# как активировать textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт который прекращает отправку формы, если текстовое поле пустое.
Как сделать так, что если поле пустое - форма не отправлялась, а `textarea` делался активным (т. е. как при клике на него)?

**Из комментариев:**
Как сделать еще чтобы линии стали красными, но если просто клацнули, то были нормальными?

Вот код:

```js
   $('form').submit(function(){
  // Если textarea пустое
  if(!$(this).find('textarea').val()){
    // отменяем отправку
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='page' method='POST'>
<textarea></textarea><br><input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: $(this).find('textarea').focus() ?

Comment: @Bookin да, но как вставить в код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
  if(!$(this).find('textarea').val()){
    $('textarea').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea></textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Так?

---

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  if(!$(this).find('textarea').val()){
    $('textarea').focus().css('border','2px solid red');
    return false;
  }
});
 $('textarea').click(function(){
 $(this).css('border','2px solid blue');
 });
```

Comment: а как сделать еще что бы линии стали красными но если просто клацнули то были нормальными?

Comment: @BedOmar - описал в своем ответе, как с красным бордером сделать

Answer (score 0):

Как дополнение к вашему вопросу - с красным бордером

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  if (!$(this).find('textarea').val()) {
    $('textarea').focus();
    $('textarea').css("border", "1px red solid");
    return false;
  }
});

$('textarea').on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).css("border", "1px #aaa solid");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <br />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```